# git-svn: revert a commit from a not master branch

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Well.. I did some headless committing and merging and now I am deep in the ....

Here's what I did:

1. fetched trunk with git-svn
2. branched off work
3. git commit ed stuff to work
4. git svn dcommit ted the cnanges to svn, (yes, this i where it gets interesting)
5. git checkout master
6. git merge work

In this situation, git doesn't seem to understand that the changes to svn 
are the same as in itself. It is now up to date, but when I try to

```
git svn rebase master
```

I get Invalid upstream

Comment: shouldn't that be git svn rebase?

Comment: whoopsy! you are right, Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solution to this was:
Do a hard reset on Master to a common ancestor (svn and master)

```
svn reset --hard  <somehash>
```

then I did a rebase.

Now all directions of merges work again, as far as I can tell.
I am still a total git newbie...

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebase your master branch onto the updated SVN trunk before you attempt to rebase your work branch on master.

For example:

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git checkout work
git rebase master
```

This ensures that your master branch is in sync with the SVN trunk.

Comment: Yeah I know that I messed up the proper protocol there. But this seems not to be a solution to the problem. At the point "git svn rebase " I still got an error message (don't know if it was invalid upstream too)